# Си.Не могу распечатать двумерный массив из букв

Tags: c, массивы, char, символы

Подскажите в чем ошибка..почему программа завершается досрочно?
Я должен получить 10 строк в каждой из которых по 10 букв (a..f)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fillArrayWithRandomStrings(char** arr,int n,int size,int alpha)
{
    int i, j;
    char s;
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            char c = 'a' + rand() % alpha;
            s += c;
        }
        arr[i] = s;
    }
}

void arrprint(char**arr, int n) {
    printf("%c", **arr);
    int i;
    for ( i = 1; i < n; i++) printf(" %c", arr[i]);
    puts("");
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i,j;
    long c = 0, p = 0;
    int n = 10, size = 10, alpha = 6;
    char** arr = NULL;
    arr = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    arr[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    fillArrayWithRandomStrings(arr,n,size,alpha);
    arrprint(arr, n);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Как отлаживать маленькие программы](https://habr.com/ru/post/339038/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пишите правильно, не пытайтесь складывать `char`ы в надежде получить строку, не присваивайте указателям те же `char`ы...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fillArrayWithRandomStrings(char** arr, int n, int size, int alpha)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            char c = 'a' + rand() % alpha;
            arr[i][j] = c;
        }
    }
}

void arrprint(char**arr, int n, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            printf(" %c",arr[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = 10, size = 10, alpha = 6;
    char** arr = NULL;
    arr = malloc(sizeof(char*)*n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

    fillArrayWithRandomStrings(arr,n,size,alpha);

    arrprint(arr, n, size);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(arr[i]);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```